# is it possible to translate ServerHttpRequest and HttpServletRequest each other

Tags: java, spring

I am now using spring cloud gateway, from the spring could gateway filter I could get the `ServerHttpRequest` which come from `org.springframework.http.server` like this:

```
ServerHttpRequest request = (ServerHttpRequest) exchange.getRequest();
```

but the public library function just only accept `HttpServletRequest` which was in the package `javax.servlet.http`, is it possible to translate the two type of object? or must I write a overload function with different type of parameter? should I implement twice with the same function? BTW, this is my public function:

```
public static void handleLoginCheck(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    AutoHeaderInfoRequest autoHeaderInfoRequest = AuthUtil.getAutoHeaderInfoRequest(httpServletRequest);
    if (autoHeaderInfoRequest.getAccessToken() == null) {
        throw ServiceException.NOT_LOGGED_IN_EXCEPTION;
    }
    if (!AuthUtil.verifyAccessToken(autoHeaderInfoRequest.getAccessToken())) {
        throw GlobalException.ACCESS_TOKEN_INVALID_EXCEPTION;
    }
    setRequestGlobalHeader(autoHeaderInfoRequest);
}
```

this function and all invoked function use `HttpServletRequest`.

Comment: The question is not clear. What do you want to get ? Do you want to convert exchange.getRequest() into HttpServletRequest ? Is that what you are telling ?

Comment: yes, I want to translate exchange.getRequest() into HttpServletRequest if possbile. @AnishB.

Comment: Why you want to do that ?

Comment: as I explained the public function need this, I will provide more details. @AnishB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Spring Docs:

> `ServerHttpRequest` interface implementation is based on
> `HttpServletRequest` interface.

---

Two points to be noted before you proceed:

1. The `ServerWebExchange.getRequest()` returns `org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest` and not `org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpRequest`. Otherwise, you will get `java.lang.ClassCastException`. So, modify your code.
2. It is rather impossible to return `HttpServletRequest` from `org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest` and also `org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpServlet` is a private class and can't be helpful in this case. Previously, considering the approach with `org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpServlet` was my bad.
   Spring team also doesn't recommend the use of servlets in webflux application.

---

You have to overload the public method and also modify the method calls associated with this :

```
public static void handleLoginCheck(ServerHttpRequest request) {
    HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
    if (headers.get("access_token") == null) {
        throw ServiceException.NOT_LOGGED_IN_EXCEPTION;
    }
    if (!AuthUtil.verifyAccessToken(headers.get("access_token"))) {
        throw GlobalException.ACCESS_TOKEN_INVALID_EXCEPTION;
    }
    setRequestGlobalHeader(headers);
}
```

Refer docs for more.

Comment: Are there cases where this cast will fail?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes, I got you. This is type-unsafe code. This code can lead to `java.lang.ClassCastException` if interface reference points to some other class instance rather than actual expected class instance at runtime. Updated my answer.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I was also thinking about the difference between blocking (servlet) web servers vs non-blocking (mostly non-servlet) web servers. The cast would not work in non-servlet environments.

Comment: I tried but it seems `exchange.getRequest()` never be a `ServletServerHttpRequest` instance. @AnishB. this is the minimal reproduce example: https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/java-learn

Comment: @Dolphin Then, is direct explicit type casting working for you in all your use cases ?

Comment: could not cast explicit, it tell me do not compatible about the two types of class. @AnishB.

Comment: @Dolphin How do I run your code and reproduce the same ?

Comment: just debug the dolphin-gateway project, and make a breakpint in the class `JwtAuthenticationFilter`, the `JwtAuthenticationFilter` contains the code about the convert. and then request to url:http://localhost:8081/music/1 it will reproduce. BTW, I am using JDK11@AnishB.

Comment: @Dolphin I have updated my answer. Kindly check.