# what is the difference about ServletServerHttpRequest and ServerHttpRequest

Tags: java, spring

I am using reactive spring, now I found the class `ServletServerHttpRequest`. what the class `ServletServerHttpRequest` designed for? is it possible to get `ServletServerHttpRequest` from reactive http request `org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest`?

Answer (score 1):

From `ServletServerHttpRequest` [Javadocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/server/ServletServerHttpRequest.html):

> Adapt ServerHttpRequest to the Servlet HttpServletRequest.

`ServletServerHttpRequest` is an implementation of `ServerHttpRequest` used when reactive application runs on servlet container.

If you are sure, that the actual instance of `ServetHttpRequest` is `ServletServerHttpRequest` you can just cast it.

Comment: I tried to cast follow this question, but encount the same problem.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69256838/is-it-possible-to-translate-serverhttprequest-and-httpservletrequest-each-other @Maciej Walkowiak

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation [Reactive-Class-Use](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework/spring-web/5.0.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/http/server/reactive/class-use/ServerHttpRequest.html)

```
public class ServletServerHttpRequest
extends AbstractServerHttpRequest
```

and relationship between `org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest` is that,

Methods inherited from interface `org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest` is `mutate`

```
mutate()
```

Return a builder to mutate properties of this request by wrapping it with ServerHttpRequestDecorator and returning either mutated values or delegating back to this instance.